# using requestbin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I'm trying to post data to http://requestb.in/ by using the code below.  However, I continue to get HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.  I'm just trying to see the JSON format of my data in my code below.

Thanks for any ideas that may lead me to a solution.  I'm using Fiddler to locate the error that I mention in my first paragraph.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PostJSON.aspx.cs" Inherits="SimpleJSONPost.PostJSON" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">    
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button1").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://requestb.in/1g8nene1",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.Stringify({"name": "John"}),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) { alert("Post Succeeded: " + msg) },
                error: function (msg) { alert("Post Failed: " + msg) }
            });
        });
    });    
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="PostJSON" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Possible problems:

1. 404 can be because RequestBin expires URLs and your URL might be expired.
2. Another problem can be with JavaScript, it is `JSON.stringify` and not `JSON.Stringify`.
3. RequestBin returns `text/plain` and you are using `dataType: "json"`. You should use `dataType: "text"` to test against RequestBin.
4. RequestBin doesn't allow CORS causing: *XMLHttpRequest cannot load '...' No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access.*

Even if you "fix" 1, 2 and 3 the item 4 will not let it work.

A possible solution is to use [PutsReq](http://putsreq.com), it allows CORS and you can configure the response to be a valid JSON.

Sample PustReq Response Builder:

```
response.status = 200;
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
response.body = { 'msg': 'ok' };
```

Your Ajax call (replace *YOUR-TOKEN* with a valid PutsReq token):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://putsreq.herokuapp.com/<YOUR-TOKEN>",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "name": "John" }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) { alert("Post Succeeded: " + msg) },
    error: function (msg) { alert("Post Failed: " + msg) }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has something to do with your problem, but why do you "stringify" your sent data?

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://requestb.in/1g8nene1",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: {"name": "John"},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (msg) { alert("Post Succeeded: " + msg) },
  error: function (msg) { alert("Post Failed: " + msg) }
});

Send it as a plain object, jQuery will take care of everything. I've changed it on a local test to see your problem and the response status is 200 to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have taken the Json.Stringify function out but still get an error.  In fact, my error output says Post Failed: [object Object].